# Почему не работает алгоритм закрашивания замкнутой области winforms c#?

Tags: c#

```
void floodFill(int x, int y, Color oldcolor, Color newcolor)
{
    Stack<Point> stackPixels = new Stack<Point>();

    bmp = new Bitmap(panelPaint.Width, panelPaint.Height);

    panelPaint.BackgroundImage = (Image)bmp;
    panelPaint.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.None;

    // 1. Поместить затравочный пиксел в стек;
    stackPixels.Push(new Point(x, y));

    Point currentPixel;
    do
    {
        // 2. Извлечь пиксел из стека;
        currentPixel = stackPixels.Pop();
        // 3. Присвоить пикселу требуемое значение(цвет внутренней области);
        bmp.SetPixel(currentPixel.X, currentPixel.Y, newcolor);

        //grPanel.DrawLine(currentPen, currentPixel.X, currentPixel.Y, currentPixel.X, currentPixel.Y);

        // 4. Каждый окрестный пиксел добавить в стек, если он

        // 4.1. Не является граничным;                
        if (currentPixel.X-1 > 0 && currentPixel.X-1 < bmp.Width && currentPixel.Y > 0 && currentPixel.Y < bmp.Height)
        {
            // 4.2. Не обработан ранее(т.е.его цвет отличается от цвета границы или цвета внутренней области);
            if (bmp.GetPixel(currentPixel.X - 1, currentPixel.Y).ToArgb() == oldcolor.ToArgb())
            {
                stackPixels.Push(new Point(currentPixel.X - 1, currentPixel.Y));
            }
        }

        if (currentPixel.X + 1 > 0 && currentPixel.X + 1 < bmp.Width && currentPixel.Y > 0 && currentPixel.Y < bmp.Height)
        {
            if (bmp.GetPixel(currentPixel.X + 1, currentPixel.Y).ToArgb() == oldcolor.ToArgb())
            {
                stackPixels.Push(new Point(currentPixel.X + 1, currentPixel.Y));
            }                       
        }

        if (currentPixel.X > 0 && currentPixel.X < bmp.Width && currentPixel.Y - 1 > 0 && currentPixel.Y - 1 < bmp.Height)
        {                    
            if (bmp.GetPixel(currentPixel.X, currentPixel.Y - 1).ToArgb() == oldcolor.ToArgb())
            {
                stackPixels.Push(new Point(currentPixel.X, currentPixel.Y - 1));
            }                      
        }

       if (currentPixel.X > 0 && currentPixel.X < bmp.Width && currentPixel.Y + 1 > 0 && currentPixel.Y + 1 < bmp.Height)
        {                    
            if (bmp.GetPixel(currentPixel.X, currentPixel.Y + 1).ToArgb() == oldcolor.ToArgb())
            {
                stackPixels.Push(new Point(currentPixel.X, currentPixel.Y + 1));
            }
        }
    } while (stackPixels.Count != 0); // 5. Если стек не пуст, перейти к шагу 2
}
```

Comment: Вы пробовали запускать в режиме отладки? Переформулируйте условия задачи и поясните вашу логику.

Comment: Задача - закрасить замкнутую область(например квадрат), нарисованный на панеле. Отлаживал, походу в бит мапе нету пикселей фигуры))) странно

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, чтобы закрасить замкнутую область нужна картинка с этой областью, у вас алгоритм не работает с исходным изображением.
Во-вторых, вы сравниваете по 4-связности цвет соседних пикселей с цветом границы, но не сравниваете их с цветом заливки - это выльется в бесконечное перекрашивание области.

Переписал по вашему алгоритму (без проверок на файл, выход за границы и тд.)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Bitmap image;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void openFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            image = new Bitmap(openFileDialog.FileName);
            Bitmap newImage = PaintZone(image, 17, 50, Color.FromArgb(76, 178, 212), Color.Black);
            panelPaint.BackgroundImage = newImage;
        }
    }

    private Bitmap PaintZone(Bitmap sourceImage, int x, int y, Color color, Color borderColor)
    {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap)sourceImage.Clone();
        Stack<Point> points = new Stack<Point>();
        points.Push(new Point(x, y));

        Point currentPoint;
        while (points.Count != 0)
        {
            currentPoint = points.Pop();
            image.SetPixel(currentPoint.X, currentPoint.Y, color);

            Color topPixel = image.GetPixel(currentPoint.X, currentPoint.Y + 1);
            if (topPixel.ToArgb() != borderColor.ToArgb() && topPixel.ToArgb() != color.ToArgb())
            {
                points.Push(new Point(currentPoint.X, currentPoint.Y + 1));
            }

            Color rightPixel = image.GetPixel(currentPoint.X + 1, currentPoint.Y);
            if (rightPixel.ToArgb() != borderColor.ToArgb() && rightPixel.ToArgb() != color.ToArgb())
            {
                points.Push(new Point(currentPoint.X + 1, currentPoint.Y));
            }

            Color bottomPixel = image.GetPixel(currentPoint.X, currentPoint.Y - 1);
            if (bottomPixel.ToArgb() != borderColor.ToArgb() && bottomPixel.ToArgb() != color.ToArgb())
            {
                points.Push(new Point(currentPoint.X, currentPoint.Y - 1));
            }

            Color leftPixel = image.GetPixel(currentPoint.X - 1, currentPoint.Y);
            if (leftPixel.ToArgb() != borderColor.ToArgb() && leftPixel.ToArgb() != color.ToArgb())
            {
                points.Push(new Point(currentPoint.X - 1, currentPoint.Y));
            }
        }

        return image;
    }
}
```

Демонстрация:

[image: Исходное изображение]
[image: Заполненная область изображения]

Comment: Демонстрация зачет :)

Comment: @БогданВаловый если вам ответ помог - отметьте его как правильный.